# How to include a stop program function in a script in python 3.5

Tags: function, python-3.x, exit

I want to program a function `terminate()` that stops the current program based on user input. In real I have had some issues with this, sometimes it's working with including `sys.exit()` in the function, sometimes not. Sometimes `quit()` is working, sometimes not. 'Sometimes' means, that it's depending from what part of the programm the function terminate() is being called. What can be the reason and what can be used alternatively?

I tried to replicate another issue below: 
`func1()` calls `func2()` in order to receive some input variables. During the input procedure in func(2) the user can opt to enter 'stop'. In this case `terminate()` is called and the program should be exited. But it does not.

It appears to me that it first jumps back to `func1()` and terminates then with an error message that the result is not iterable. How can I prevent this jump back to `func1()` and stop the program already in `terminate()`?

```
import sys

def func1():
    a, b = func2() 
    print('something's brewing and I don't know what it is.')

def func2():
    check = 0
    while check < 1: 
        x = input( 'your choice: ')
        if x == 'stop':
            terminate('stop')
            break
        else:
            a = x

        y = input( 'your choice: ')
        if y == 'stop':
            terminate('stop')
        else:
            b = y
        check = 1
    return a, b

def terminate(stop):
    if stop == 'stop':
        sys.exit()
        # or quit()
    else:
        return False

print(func1())
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your program has a syntax error in the first line of `terminate()`.  If you fix that, it still doesn't run because you never call a function.  Please give code that reproduces the problem, and test it before you post it.

Comment: thanks @zondo. I did some amendments. As I described the problems appear sometimes and I don't know how to replicate it exactly. Hoping I get some input what the reasons can be. What is most stunning is the fact that somehow the sys.exit() behaves differently depending on from where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

As for the 'jump back', I cannot offer you any advice, however, I can offer a cleaner solution which makes use of Python's error handling.

Alternative to calling `quit()` or `sys.exit()`:

```
import sys

# Declare a custom Exception which you can catch
class ProcessTerminated(Exception):
    pass

def func1():
    a, b = func2() 
    print('something's brewing and I don't know what it is.')

def func2():
    check = 0
    while check < 1: 
        x = input( 'your choice: ')
        if x == 'stop':
            terminate('stop')
            break
        else:
            a = x

        y = input( 'your choice: ')
        if y == 'stop':
            terminate()
        else:
            b = y
        check = 1
    return a, b

def terminate(stop):
    raise ProcessTerminated()  # Raise this and catch it in main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print(func1())
    except ProcessTerminated:
        print("Process terminated successfully!")
```